# Python If Else statement syntax error

Tags: python, loops, generics, if-statement

I'm just playing around with If Else statements and I'm wondering how to get it to loop round to asking the question again if the first If Else is true.

Furthermore, how would you add a generic Else on the end to make it say something for any other names that are put in?

I'm in `Python 2.7` on the `Raspberry Pi.`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

name=""
while name !="quit":
 name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
 print "Hello", name
 import time
 time.sleep(2)
 if name == "Jack":
   print "Jack, I have decided that you are awesome."
   time.sleep(2)
   print "And I am a computer so I cannot be wrong"
 else:
   print "Oh, you are not Jack?"
   time.sleep(2)
   print "Haha, Jack is better than you"
 if name == "Ronan":
   print "Ronan, I know everything about you."
   time.sleep(2)
   print "For example, I know you hate cats."
 else:
   print "Oh, you are not Ronan?"
   time.sleep(2)
   print "Perhaps you can convince him that he loves cats"
```

Comment: `print "Haha, Jack is better than you` needs an end quote.

Comment: Yes, sorry any other mistakes I have fixed already, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close parentheses at `print "Haha, Jack is better than you` line.

You should `import time` only once, out of while loop, preferably at the start of a script. You don't need to import it `while name !="quit"`.

And `if/else` construction should look like this:

```
if something:
    #do something

elif otherthing:
    #do something else

else:
    #if everything above fails, do this
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing quote on this line `print "Jack, I have decided that you are awesome."` The `break` command on the last line will help terminate the loop.

```
 name=""
while name !="quit":
 name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
 print "Hello", name
 import time
 time.sleep(2)
 if name == "Jack":
   print "Jack, I have decided that you are awesome."
   time.sleep(2)
   print "And I am a computer so I cannot be wrong"
 else:
   print "Oh, you are not Jack?"
   time.sleep(2)
   print "Haha, Jack is better than you"
 if name == "Ronan":
   print "Ronan, I know everything about you."
   time.sleep(2)
   print "For example, I know you hate cats."
 else:
   print "Oh, you are not Ronan?"
   time.sleep(2)
   print "Perhaps you can convince him that he loves cats"
 if name != "jack" and name != "Ronan":
   print "I am not wrong"

 break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` which will return execution to the top of the loop.

```
 if name == "Jack":
   print "Jack, I have decided that you are awesome."
   time.sleep(2)
   print "And I am a computer so I cannot be wrong"
   continue
```

But really you need to restructure your if...else statement.

Also your loop termination logic is not quite right, this would be better:

```
while True:
    name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    if name.lower() in ('quit', 'exit', 'end', 'bye'):
        break

    print "Hello", name
    if name == "Jack":
    .
    .
    .
```

As for your if statements, because you have else clauses for each name, a generic catch all is slightly difficult. You can check at the end like this:

```
KNOWN_NAMES = ('Jack', 'Ronan', 'Whomever')
QUIT_VERBS = ('quit', 'q', 'exit', 'end', 'bye')

while True:
    name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    if name.lower() in QUIT_VERBS:
        break

    if name == "Jack":
        print "Jack, I have decided that you are awesome."
        time.sleep(2)
        print "And I am a computer so I cannot be wrong"
    else:
        print "Oh, you are not Jack?"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Haha, Jack is better than you"
    if name == "Ronan":
        # etc, etc

    if name not in KNOWN_NAMES:
        print 'I know nothing about no "%s"' % name
```